# how to get microphone permission when button is clicked in extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                                audio: {
                                    echoCancellation: !0,
                                    channelCount: 1,
                                    sampleRate: {
                                        ideal: e
                                    },
                                    sampleSize: i
                                }
                            })
```

it return promise value Rejected and promise status `DOM:Shutdown`

Comment: It needs the invoking process to be a tab, which the popup is not. Either open a new window or tab or ask the permission in your content script.

Comment: can you give me example. i have ask for permission in content script but  how it will have impact on permission Request in popup.html

Comment: The above code will be the same. If you need examples of opening windows in javascript, you can easily google them up.

Comment: i go the permission from content script but how can i use this permission  for extension popup

Comment: Like I said, you can't do it in the extension popup.

Comment: but i want to use the promise return in popup